# C++ error for push method on vector

Tags: c++, vector, push

I am new with using c++, so please excuse me on this a little bit. I am trying to implement a push function that add an item at the end of a Template Vector. Although I am using the push_back function associated with the Vector, I am receiving an error message that I cannot explain.

Update: I know that it is improper to implement the functions within header files, but this is how the project has been set up for me, and I need to make it run.  The code below is for "stac_vec_tpt.h."

I hope this clears things up a little bit more.

Below is the code for header file in use:

```
#ifndef _STACK_VEC_TPT_H_
#define _STACK_VEC_TPT_H_
#include <stdexcept>

using namespace std;

// abstract stack class implemented using vector
template<class T>
class abs_stack_vec {
public:
// pushes an element onto the top of the stack. 
// grows the vector if needed.
virtual void push(const T& elem)=0;

// pops an element from the top of the stack.
// does nothing if the stack is empty.
virtual void pop()=0;

// returns the value of the top element on the stack.
// throws domain_error if the stack is empty.
virtual const T& top() const=0;

// returns the number of elements currently on the stack.
virtual unsigned size() const=0;
};

// the following class inherits from the abstract stack class
// using its own implementation of a vector
// you must implement the abstract methods push, pop, and top.
template<class T>
class mystack_vec: public abs_stack_vec<T> {
public:
    unsigned size() const {return _size;}

// method used for growing vector when size equals capacity
// and need to add more elements
void grow() {
    T* temp = new T[_size * 2];
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < _size; ++i) {
        temp[i] = _values[i];
    }
    delete[] _values;
    _values = temp;
    _capacity = _size * 2;
}

// default constructor
mystack_vec() {
    _capacity = 5;
    _size = 0;
    _values = new T[_capacity];
}

//destructor
~mystack_vec() {
    delete[] _values;
}

// TO-DO: YOU MUST IMPLEMENT: PUSH
void push(const T& elem) {
    mystack_vec.push_back();
}
// END OF TO-DO

private:
    T *_values; // array !!
    unsigned _size, _capacity;
};
#endif
```

Also the error message that I am receiving is as follows: Error 1   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '.'  Line 62

Line 62 is for the statement "mystack_vec.push_back();," inside void push().

Comment: did you mean `this->push_back` ?

Comment: Why don't you just use `std::vector`?

Comment: And... Shouldn't you be doing this->push_back(elem); ? Assuming you are using std::vector or at least something similar.

Comment: Is `mystack_vec` the name of the class or the name of a variable? And shouldn't you provide an argument to the call?

Comment: @jules I tried this->push_back(elem) and it threw the error "push_back is not a member of mystack_vec."
Im trying to get this to work through the template and not using the std::vector.  Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

To fix the syntax error, you need to tell the compiler that the implementations belong to `mystack_vec`:

```
template<typename T>
mystack_vec<T>::~mystack_vec() {
    delete[] _values;
}

template<typename T>
void mystack_vec<T>::push(const T& elem) {
    // The implementation needs to check if you have enough capacity, 
    // grow _values if necessary,
    // and store elem in the _values[_size++]
}
```

Implementing the `push` operator is the beef of your exercise. It is not hard, given that you've got a working `grow()` function. Three steps that you need to follow in your implementation are explained in the comments above.

Comment: Shouldn't this be `template<typename T> void mystack_vec<T>::push(const T& elem) { ...`??

Answer (score 0):

`mystack_vec` is a type, not an object. The only calls you can make on it are for static functions, and those would use `::` instead of `.`. The error message comes about because it's expecting you to declare a variable or something, and didn't expect the `.` at that spot.

Comment: From the .cpp file, there is a vector created through the template mystack_vec for int type. Then it simply treats the vector as a stack, using push, pop methods.
I am having a hard time understanding how to actually write the push method, because I'm not familiar with the purpose of a template in cpp. The concept of making this run through the template is throwing me off. I was under the impression that I could simply use the mystack_vec as though it was already created. 
Also, when I try this->push_back it throws an error as well.

Answer (score 0):

Access the array stated at the bottom of the header file provided

```
`private:
    T *_values; // array !!
    unsigned _size, _capacity;
};`
```

Then implement the following code for the push method:

```
    void push(const T& elem) {
    if (_capacity == _size)
    {
        grow();
    }

    _values[_size] = elem;
    _size++;
}
```